# How can I send a print to a word document saved with a specific name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to take this:

```
for k, v in r.items():
    f.write(str(v) + " " + str(k) + "\n")
```

and print it into a Word document, then save that word document with a name that I provide from within the code. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. One way is by using `pickle`, as shown below:

**Pickle**

```py
import pickle
r = dict(reduce(f, lines, defaultdict(int)))
print(r)
filename = 'foobar.docx' #docx is default Word extension
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(r, outfile)
outfile.close()
```

Another way is through the `save()` method, as shown below:

**Save**

```py
r = dict(reduce(f, lines, defaultdict(int)))
print(r)
filename = 'foobar.docx' #docx is default Word extension
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
save(r, outfile)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: BTW the save code might not work properly, I don't understand it perfectly yet

Comment: Tried both methods, Save method just crashed and pickle method created unreadable content for word. The other answer also creates unreadable content. I am getting it into notepad without issue using: with open("output.txt", "w") as f: 
       for k, v in r.items():
         f.write(str(v) + " " + str(k) + "\n")     I think notepad is fine, there's probably a converter I can find online to convert them later if needed.

Comment: That's unexpected! Could you please describe the `save()` method crash for me?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to append to a Word document or do you want to create the file?

Here is how to create a file and write your data to it:

```
with open(r'pathforfile/name.docx', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(r)
```

Comment: Similar to what I had tried. I am currently saving as txt document without issue, when I switch to docx word is unable to open it. The current code is: with open(r"output.docx", "w+") as f:  
  for k, v in r.items():
    f.write(str(v) + " " + str(k) + "\n")

Comment: Ah okey, so the problem is when you try to open the file afterwards it doesnt open? 

I dont have Office on this current PC, so i can't try, but it looks like you need to use the python-docx library…

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yeah exactly. I was thinking the same thing. I was hoping there was a really simple method but it appears not. I will just use notepad for now, it's not a huge issue.

Comment: Yeah i thought it was possible to just write to a .docx-file… Im sorry :/

Comment: No worries! Funny that you had the same thought as me haha